# How to add a String to duplicate element in Array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, duplicates

I have following array:

```
$array = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'
```

I want to identify the duplicate and add to the duplicate a string, for example, `$string='Part 2'`

so that I have

```
$array = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A Part 2'
```

How do I do this in PowerShell?

Comment: I tried two loops through this array but it didnt work

Comment: `$array = 'A';'B';'C';'A'` <-- `;` is not an array item separator, this is just 1 assignment and 3 string literals - did you mean `$array = 'A','B','C','A'`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yeah exactly. Its just an normal Array

Comment: And is _casing_ important? Is `A` and `a` considered duplicates, or two distinct strings?

Comment: I just want to change the duplicate within an array for example by inserting a string

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Casing is not important

Comment: The `-contains` operator is an alternative to the answers posted. `if($array -contains 'c'){...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a hashtable to keep track of strings you've already seen, then loop through all items in the array - if we've already seen the same, modify the item, otherwise leave it as is:

```
$array = 'A','B','C','A'

# Create hashtable to keep track of strings we've already encountered
$stringsSeen = @{}

# Now iterate over the array
$modifiedArray = $array |ForEach-Object {
  if(!$stringsSeen.ContainsKey($_)){
    # First encounter, add to hashtable
    $stringsSeen[$_] = 1
  }
  else {
    # We've seen it before! Time to update value and modify `$_`
    $number = ++$stringsSeen[$_]
    $_ += " Part $number"
  }

  # finally output `$_`, regardless of whether we modified it or not
  $_
}
```

`$modifiedArray` now holds the new array of (partially) modified strings:

```
PS ~> $modifiedArray
A
B
C
A Part 2
```

Answer (score 3):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67486771/45375) shows an effective, readable solution.

The following solution *streamlines* the approach to make it more concise (though thereby potentially more obscure) and more efficient:

- The [`.ForEach()` array *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) is used to process the input array, as a faster alternative to the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*. (A `foreach` *statement* would be even faster, but is a bit more verbose).
- It relies on the (non-obvious) fact that `++` applied to a non-existent hashtable entry implicitly creates the entry with value `1`.

```
$array = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'

$ht = @{}
$newArray = $array.ForEach(
  { if (($count = ++$ht[$_]) -eq 1) { $_ } else { "$_ Part $count" } }
)
```

<sup>Note: `$newArray` is technically not an *array*, but of type `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`, but that usually won't make a difference.</sup>

In [**PowerShell (Core) 7+**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) an even more concise solution is possible, using `?:`, the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false):

```
$array = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'

$ht = @{}
$newArray = $array.ForEach({ ($count = ++$ht[$_]) -eq 1 ? $_ : "$_ Part $count" })
```

Comment: I'm afraid I've packed away all my golf clothes for the season xD

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen :) Yes, I know such solutions aren't for everyone, but I hope at least some readers find them helpful, especially those familiar with `awk`.